# Center TextView in custom ActionBar horizontally

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

A want to create custom ActionBar with app name in center of it but it is still aligned to left. Here is xml of *custom_actionbar.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@color/transparent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nav_bar_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/sue_green"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge">
        </TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is on create of Activity:

```
public class DeviceOverviewActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_FULL_SENSOR);

        setTheme(R.style.Theme_SUE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_device_overview);

        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);

        LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) this .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar, null);

        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setCustomView(v);
    }
...
}
```

Can you advice what am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Try with a LinearLayout, and remove this line android:layout_centerInParent="true"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `TextView`s width to `match_parent` and apply a `android:gravity="center_horizontal"`

Answer (score 0):

use android support `ToolBar` for custom actionbar..

use this link for [Tool bar](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up.html) reference